# Center video zoom

Tags: html, css, video

I have a video which is set on full window height with this css style

```
width: auto;
height: 100vh;
min-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
background-attachment: fixed;
left: 0px;
object-fit: fill;
z-index: -1;
overflow: hidden;
```

but the problem is, that when i open it on mobile, the video is zoomed to left bottom corner. Is there any way how to zoom to center?

Comment: Unfortunately you don't provide any HTML, or simplified, minimalistic reproduction of your issue. Please do so. But my wild guess - based on your CSS - is that it has to do with `left: 0px`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: You'll probably want to add the vertical aspect as well since OP problem is left **bottom** corner.